# Python 2.7.13 How to find words in multiple strings/lists?

Tags: python

I need to execute a command if a word is in a list for example;

```
arrangement_01 = [['Block A', 'Bottom left', 'Up', 'O']]

arrangement_02 = [['Block B', 'Bottom right', 'Up', 'O']]

arrangement_03 = [['Block C', 'Bottom left', 'Up', 'O']]

arrangement_04 = [['Block D', 'Bottom right', 'Up', 'O']]

arrangement_52 = [['Block B', 'Bottom left', 'Down', 'O'],
              ['Block A', 'Bottom right', 'Left', 'O'],
              ['Block D', 'Top left', 'Right', 'O'],
              ['Block C', 'Top right', 'Up', 'X']]
```

If 'Block A' is in any arrangement (listed above)
How can I can define a function so it will execute a command? for example;

```
def stack_blocks(arrangement?)
    if 'Block A' in anyarrangement
    draw_blocka()

stack_blocks(arrangement_01)
```

(I know this is wrong, but any ideas?)

Sorry if I didn't explain this well.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to test whether a particular block is present in any of the "arrangements", you could first extract all of them, save it as a set and then use this set for testing:

```
from itertools import chain

arrangement_01 = [['Block A', 'Bottom left', 'Up', 'O']]

arrangement_02 = [['Block B', 'Bottom right', 'Up', 'O']]

arrangement_03 = [['Block C', 'Bottom left', 'Up', 'O']]

arrangement_04 = [['Block D', 'Bottom right', 'Up', 'O']]

arrangement_52 = [['Block B', 'Bottom left', 'Down', 'O'],
               ['Block A', 'Bottom right', 'Left', 'O'],
               ['Block D', 'Top left', 'Right', 'O'],
               ['Block C', 'Top right', 'Up', 'X']]

omega = set([])
for L in chain(arrangement_01, arrangement_02, arrangement_03 , arrangement_04, arrangement_52):
    omega.add(L[0])

if 'Block A' in omega:
    print('Block A is present in some of the arrangements')
```

Answer (score 0):

Flatten your arrangements before you check the existence of the specific word.

```
arrangement = [word for item in arrangement for word in item]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your function slightly modified:

```
def stack_blocks(arrangement, checkval)
    Ret checkval in  
        [elem for sublist in  arrangement for elem in sublist]

Stack_blocks(arrangement1, "Block A")
# returns true
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick :

```
arrangement_01 = [['Block A', 'Bottom left', 'Up', 'O']]

arrangement_02 = [['Block B', 'Bottom right', 'Up', 'O']]

arrangement_03 = [['Block C', 'Bottom left', 'Up', 'O']]

arrangement_04 = [['Block D', 'Bottom right', 'Up', 'O']]

arrangement_52 = [['Block B', 'Bottom left', 'Down', 'O'],
              ['Block A', 'Bottom right', 'Left', 'O'],
              ['Block D', 'Top left', 'Right', 'O'],
              ['Block C', 'Top right', 'Up', 'X']]


def stack_blocks(arrangement):
    for item in arrangement:
        if 'Block A' in item:
            print "its there"

for value in vars().values():
    if isinstance(value, list):
        stack_blocks(value);
```

What you do over here is that you get all the variables defined and then check if their value contains a list or not :

```
if isinstance(value, list):
```

If this evaluates to true, we pass the variable value to the function where you can implement your logic.

Hope this helped.